# GNU debugger; eclipse throws error message

Tags: eclipse, debugging, cygwin

I spent almost an hour looking for something specific related to gdb debugger installed inside Cygwin. have seen many people facing the same problem but not any useful answer to that. I need to use gcc debugger inside my c/c++ enabled eclipse. 
every time I'm trying to launch the debugger I'm getting an error that gdb --version can't be determined. 
I went deep through performing some checkups, I get this:

> $ gdb --version:
>
> > /usr/bin/gdb.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygexpat-1.dll: cannot open shared >object file: No such file or directory

pulling up Cygwin command prompt, I get this as a result:

> $ cygcheck gdb:
>
> > cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygexpat-1.dll

I know there has to be a way to make the GNU debugger work in eclipse, help me out.

Comment: You need to use a proper win32 version of GDB. Cygnwin's one runs inside its shell (using it's virtual rappresentation of the file system and using unix style paths), on windows there's no LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Didn't really get what you meant. would you elaborate the steps more?

Comment: Eclipse sees the win32 enviroment, gdb inside cygwin sees the cygwin unix like emulated enviroment (proxyed by cyglib.dll). You need a gdb version not depending on cygwin enviroment

Comment: But the error message I get is coming from executing gdb debugger inside the cygwin unix emulator; probably these two have been integrated to work with each other. Don' you think?

Comment: in cygwin shell do an "echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH" and check it. If you're on a recent windows version there was some rebase to do with cygwin, gonna check if I still have some references.

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine had the same problem (he couldn't run gdb in a Cygwin terminal). The fix was to install the 'expat' package in the 'Libs' category.

In the interest of teaching a person to fish, here's how I figured this out:

```
$ cygcheck -p cygexpat-1.dll
Found 5 matches for cygexpat-1.dll
x86/cygwin64-expat/cygwin64-expat-2.1.0-2
x86/expat-debuginfo/expat-debuginfo-2.1.0-2
x86/expat-debuginfo/expat-debuginfo-2.1.0-3
x86/libexpat1/libexpat1-2.1.0-2
x86/libexpat1/libexpat1-2.1.0-3
```

In the Cygwin installer I made the reasonable guess that 'expat' in the installer UI and 'x86/libexpat1' were the same package. It's a bit confusing.

I'm still not sure how his gdb got installed without the required dependencies. Also, '`cygcheck -c`' gave his setup a clean bill of health.

Answer (score 0):

Install libexpat1 which is under Libs